# Why does a JTextField shrink in size to 0 when passed a large column's number?

Tags: java, swing

Apparently if the columns size is more than 70 the field get's displayed with a size where you cannot even type a single character?
I'm talking about:

```
new JTextField(70);
```

Comment: Could you post some code? It might be your LayoutManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing in the number of columns adjusts the text field's *preferred size*. As camickr points out, you may be using a layout that under certain circumstances will use the minimum size which is zero.

If you wish to *force* the minimum size to be the preferred size (and that may or may not be a good idea), you can do:

```
textField.setMinimumSize(textField.getPreferredSize());
```

Comment: this works, except for that it squeezes the other components. Need to tell it to resize the components somehow (fontwise).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using a GridBagLayout. If there is not enough space to display the component at its preferred size the component shrinks to its minimum size which I believe is 0. Try giving your component a minimum size or use a different layout manager.

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).